# Error en App Android

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Espero que se encuentren bien.

Disculpen las molestias pero estoy desarrollando una app y al momento de colocar el atributo

```
tools:showIn="@layout/app_layaut_principal
```

con el XML señalado me arroja el siguiente error.

> The surrounding layout (@layout/app_layaut_principal) did not actually
> include this layout. Remove tools:showIn=... from the root tag.

De casualidad alguien sabe como puedo solucionar el error señalado.

De antemano se los agradeceré.

Que dios Los Bendiga A Tod@s.

Saludos, Cordiales...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_layaut_principal">

</RelativeLayout
```

> 

Comment: Es muy simple, te está diciendo que quites esto del XML: `tools:showIn="@layout/app_layaut_principal"` porque `app_layaut_principal` ya no usa ese `RelativeLayout`. Por cierto, revisa que tu archivo se llama realmente `app_layaut_principal`, aunque debería llamarse `app_layout_principal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy simple, te está diciendo que quites esto del XML:

```
tools:showIn="@layout/app_layaut_principal"
```

porque `app_layaut_principal` no usa ese `RelativeLayout` mediante `include`.

Imaginemos que el código que nos muestras está en el archivo: **`res/layout/layout_parcial.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_layaut_principal">  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Y que también tienes un archivo: **`res/layout/app_layaut_principal.xml`** (OJO a un posible error de *typo* en *layaut*) con contenido como este o parecido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!-- Aquí más código -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

El error ocurrirá, porque no estás incluyendo a `layout_parcial` en `app_layaut_principal`.

Entonces, si lo necesitas debes incluirlo:

**`res/layout/app_layaut_principal.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!-- Aquí más código -->

    <include layout="@layout/layout_parcial"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Si no lo necesitas, quita el `showIn`.

**`res/layout/layout_parcial.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">  

</RelativeLayout>
```

En Android, tú puedes [re-utilizar layouts](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts), definiéndolos aparte y luego incluyéndolos con `include`, y el uso de `showIn` te permite ver una vista previa en su conjunto y editarla. Para más detalles, [consulta la documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsshowin).

Comment: Hola Amigo. Espero Estes Bien. 

Primero que nada quiero agradecerte por que Me Acabas de salvar, tu respuesta fue de gran utilidad mi amigo.

Que dios Te Bendiga y  Enserio Gracias por tu valiosa respuesta amigo.

Saludos Coordiales..